# How to test for null in Linq without new keyword?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq query like this.

```
  (from r in list2 where r.RowLevel == 0 select r.SortOrder).Max()
```

My problem is that sometimes this returns no records, so i want to get 0 in that kind of situation without creating a new object after the `select` keyword.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 (from r in list2 where r.RowLevel == 0 select r.SortOrder).DefaultIfEmpty().Max()
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: Link to documentation: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360179(v=vs.100).aspx)